# Changing an existing column to be an identity

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change programmatically non-identity column to identity one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756354/how-to-change-programmatically-non-identity-column-to-identity-one)

I want to set a column as identity
as I have already created this column in a table.

What syntax do I need? `ALTER ...` ?

Comment: It may not matter (I can't remember all the syntaxes) but which database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add the identity to an existing column, you must create a new column.

Answer (score 1):

With a table Test

```
create table Test(ID int)
```

You can do this

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.Test', 'tmp_Test', 'OBJECT'
go

create table dbo.Test(
  ID int not null identity
)
go

set identity_insert dbo.Test on
go

insert into dbo.Test(ID) select ID from dbo.tmp_Test
go

set identity_insert dbo.Test off
go

drop table dbo.tmp_Test
go
```

Answer (score 0):

IN SMSS right click on your table ->modify. Choose your column ->Identity Specification->Is Identity->Yes.

Comment: This will drop the table and recreate it

Answer (score -4):

Using SQL you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName> ADD CONSTRAINT PK_<TableName> PRIMARYKEY(Column)
```

Comment: He's asking how to apply identity to an existing column, not how to add a primary key.