# How do I add auto_increment to a column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, auto-increment

I am using SQL Server 2008 and a primary key of a database table I am using is not an `IDENTITY` column (not sure why). I need to change that.

I am in SQL Server Management Studio in design view, under column properties and for some reason I can't change the identity specifications to `Yes`.

Is there something that I am missing.. I am new to SQL Server - any ideas on what I am missing??

Here is the create table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AR_Transactions](
       [Trans_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
       [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
       [Cashier_ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
       [CustNum] [nvarchar](12) NOT NULL,
       [Trans_Type] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
       [Prev_Cust_Balance] [money] NULL,
       [Prev_Inv_Balance] [money] NULL,
       [Trans_Amount] [money] NOT NULL,
       [Payment_Method] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
       [Payment_Info] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
       [Description] [nvarchar](38) NULL,
       [Invoice_Number] [bigint] NOT NULL,
       [Store_ID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
       [Dirty] [bit] NOT NULL,
       [Station_ID] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
       [Payment_Type] [smallint] NULL,

CONSTRAINT [pkAR_Transactions] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Store_ID] ASC, [Trans_ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AR_Transactions] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_AR_Transactions_Trans_ID_AR_Transactions] 
    DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Trans_ID]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AR_Transactions] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_AR_Transactions_Invoice_Number_AR_Transactions] 
    DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Invoice_Number]
```

Here is the query that I need to run... its a complete hack to try to auto-increment my inserts myself

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 

INSERT INTO 
        [cresql].[dbo].[AR_Transactions](Trans_ID, DateTime , Dirty, Store_ID, Trans_Type,  
            Cashier_ID, CustNum, Trans_Amount, Prev_Cust_Balance) 
        SELECT  
            (SELECT MAX(Trans_ID ) + 1 FROM [cresql].[dbo].[AR_Transactions]), 
            DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, Getdate()), 1, 1001, 'C', 100199, CustNum,
            -Acct_Balance, Acct_Balance 
    FROM  [cresql].[dbo].[Customer] 
        WHERE Acct_Balance <> 0  

UPDATE [cresql].[dbo].[Customer] 
    SET Acct_Balance = 0 
WHERE Acct_Balance <> 0  

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: What do you mean by can't change it. Does it give you an error? Is it greyed out?

Comment: Thw problem is the Is Identity is grayed out to no and i cant change it

Comment: On a side-note: I would *never* call a column something like `[DateTime]`..... and I also would recommend *not* making columns of length less than 5 `varchar` or `nvarchar` - the 2-byte overhead is just killing you. If the column is 5 chars or less, make it `CHAR(x)` or `NCHAR(x)`. And I'm sure that you're current method of increasing the `Trans_ID` is not safe in a busy environment and will sooner or later lead to duplicate `Trans_ID` values....

Comment: @marc_s – When you modified the ddl **statements** you removed the reason for his problems. You can't have a default constraint on a column with identity. I believe that is the problem and that is the reason he can't use MSSMS to change the column to be an identity column. See my answer for pretty pictures.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: ooops, sorry about that - you're totally right. With a default constraint in place, the `Identity Specification` is indeed grayed out - removing the default constraint solves this - good catch !!

Answer (score 13):

To illustrate Martin's point:

[image]

And **PS:** - as Mikael Eriksson rightfully mentions (and documents nicely), this *Identity Specification* remains grayed out as long as that column you're working on has a default constraint.

Comment: Thw problem is the Is Identity is grayed out to no and i cant change it

Comment: Exactly my point: you cannot add an identity property to a column after the fact. Nor can you get rid of it without dropping the column. The identy property **must** be defined when the column is created. Hence the 7-step tango in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You need to expand the "Identity Specification" node to change it via the `(Is Identity)` property.

This will rebuild the table so you might also need to go into `Tools -> Options -> Designers -> Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`.

This can be an extremely time consuming operation on large tables as well as entailing a lot of logging and locking. To perform this operation on a large table [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181304/set-identity-on-the-column/6094907#6094907).

Comment: +1 it's a bit tricky and not very intuitive at first - just clicking on the "Identity Specification" line doesn't do anything - one has to expand it first, and then changes can be made...

Comment: Thw problem is the Is Identity is grayed out to no and i cant change it

Comment: @Tamer - What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: You can only have one identity column per table. That's the only other thing that springs to mind. Otherwise close down SSMS and reopen it and see if you still get the problem.

Comment: yes i tried setting it and nothing...let me take a screenshot..one sec

Comment: @Tamer - Can you right click the table and choose "Script Table As -> Create" and post that into your question?

Comment: so my main reason i want to add this auto-increment is that i need to run this query and its failing...I pasted in my original question

Comment: I updated my original question with more relevant information

Comment: @Martin...any idea what is happening

Comment: @Tamer - Was offline but looks like Mikael's answer probably has it nailed.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the default constraint of column Trans_ID first. Then you can set `Is Identity` to Yes in the designer.

This is properties for column Trans_ID in your table AR_Transactions. `(Is Identity)` is disabled:

[image]

Remove the default constraint and  `(Is Identity)` is no longer disabled:

[image]

Set to yes and save. `Default Value or Binding` is disabled instead:

[image]

Comment: +1 nailed it on the head - not sure why anyone would **downvote** this absolutely spot-on response.....

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` to modify a column to have an identity property. You'll need to

- drop the primary key constraint and any foreign key constraints referencing the column in question in your table.
- add a new column with the `identity` property. It should have the same type (`int`, I presume) as the existing column.
- update the table to seed the new column with the values of the existing column.
- alter the new column to make it non-nullable.
- drop the old/existing column.
- rename the new column so that its name is the same as that of the old column.
- Recreate the primary key and foreign key references you dropped in the 1st step.

Simple! Or something.

Comment: [There is a way of doing this as a metadata only change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181304/set-identity-on-the-column/6094907#6094907) (BTW `identity` columns are not updatable so step 3 can't be done in your plan anyway)

Comment: @Martin identity columns can in fact be updated in a conversion process using Set Identity_insert ON

Comment: `set identity_insert on` allows the **insertion** of rows with a column value in identity columns; it does not allow the **update** of the value of the identity column of existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AR_Transactions](
       [Trans_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
       [Cashier_ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
       [CustNum] [nvarchar](12) NOT NULL,
       [Trans_Type] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
       [Prev_Cust_Balance] [money] NULL,
       [Prev_Inv_Balance] [money] NULL,
       [Trans_Amount] [money] NOT NULL,
       [Payment_Method] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
       [Payment_Info] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
       [Description] [nvarchar](38) NULL,
       [Invoice_Number] [bigint] NOT NULL,
       [Store_ID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
       [Dirty] [bit] NOT NULL,
       [Station_ID] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
       [Payment_Type] [smallint] NULL,

CONSTRAINT [pkAR_Transactions] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Store_ID] ASC, [Trans_ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AR_Transactions] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_AR_Transactions_Trans_ID_AR_Transactions] 
    DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Trans_ID]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AR_Transactions] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_AR_Transactions_Invoice_Number_AR_Transactions] 
    DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Invoice_Number]
```