# Setting Primary Key auto increment with Alter Command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add auto_increment to a column in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113828/how-do-i-add-auto-increment-to-a-column-in-sql-server-2008)

Hey all i created the table in gui however i forgot to set the primary key to autoincrement! name of the table is `Emp_CV`.

Something like this:

```
alter table Emp_CV alter column Applicant_ID NOT NULL int AUTO_INCREMENT
```

how can i accomplish this? 
Am using SQL Server 2008!

Comment: Can't you use the GUI editor?

Comment: no it does not allow the table to be altered once created! i have to change it with alter command!

Comment: Can you delete and recreate it?

Comment: i did not save the create query! i just want to know the right alter command to accomplish the above mentioned my assumed sql command

Comment: @burhan: that is the post once your creating a table not when you have already created it!

Comment: @HarisRiaz read the answers not the question.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is...you can't. Here's what you have to do:

1. Ensure nobody/nothing is using your table.
2. Add a new integer column that will be the new identity column. It must allow nulls and must have the appropriate identity value.
3. execute `set identity_insert dbo.foo on` -- must specify your table name.
4. Seed it with the values of the existing identity column:

   update dbo.foo set new_id = id
5. Drop any keys/constraints in which the existing identity column participates.
6. execute `set identity_insert dbo.foo off`
7. Drop the existing column.
8. Alter the new column, changing its nullity to `not null`.
9. Execute the command `dbcc checkident( {your-table-name-here} , reseed )`.
10. Execute `sp_rename` and give the new column the same name as the old column.
11. Recreate the keys/constraints dropped in step #4.
12. Might want to run `sp_recompile` on any stored procedures referencing this table.

Easy!