# Update a Current table Column to an Identity Column

Tags: sql-server, identity-column

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set identity on the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181304/set-identity-on-the-column)

I have a table let's say Messages with a column name Serno. 
Serno keeps the serial number for each message.
However system is very old and creates this serial number using max(serno) command.
Now, I am trying to change this column to an identity but I don't want to loose the current serial numbers for each message.

Is there a solution for this.

I already try to creatae a new identity column and copy the values from serno there but it doesn't work.
Neither creating a new table work as database will give new serial numbers for each message and I don't want that.

Any ideas are Welcome.

Thanks in advance

M.A

Comment: Please check this article. I think it will help you solve your issue.
[SQL SERVER – Add or Remove Identity Property on Column](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried opening the table in design view, selecting your column, and setting the `IdentitySpecification` to `Yes` (this may take a while if you have many rows, as it internally generates a complete copy of the table)

Comment: Yes I have tried this. It gives me an error that I have to re-create the table.Thanks.

Comment: In SSMS studio, select `Tools -> Options -> Designers`, then uncheck the box that is labelled `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`

Comment: I was afraid that doing so, I would loose any constraints and indexes. However I test it and works like a charm! Everything in place! Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alter the existing column and make it as an identity column.

You need to create a temporary table and insert the values to that. Finally you have to drop the actual table and rename the temp table to actual table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.NewTable(ID int IDENTITY(1, 1),<other columns>)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.NewTable ON

INSERT  INTO dbo.NewTable ( Id, <other columns>)
SELECT  Id,  <other columns> FROM    <actual_table>
go

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.NewTable OFF
go

DROP TABLE your_table
go

Exec sp_rename 'NewTable', 'actual_table'
```

Comment: Since the ID is an identity it won't let me to update this field!

Comment: @M.A: once you do SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.NewTable ON , then it will work

Comment: Since this is an insert it might work... I will try this and let u know the results. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You **can** alter the existing column and make it as an identity column. See my answer in the possible duplicate question.

Comment: I am using this : 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MessagesOLD ON

INSERT INTO MessagesOLD
select * from Messages

And I get the error:

Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'MessagesOLD' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: Martin, Can you point me to the question as I can't find it?
Thanks

Comment: @M.A. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6094907/73226). BTW use the `@` symbol when replying to people otherwise they do not get notified.